# How can I delete a tvOS app from iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect, tvos

Is there any option to delete a tvOS app from iTunes Connect? The application's current state is 'Preparing for submission.'

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for Apple's approval. After that you can manage / delete the App from iTunesConnect.

You'll get more info from documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Comment: The link seems to be dead.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [this](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev28d17ed35) documentation, you can only remove an app if **all versions** of it are in one of the following states:

> - Prepare for Submission
> - Invalid Binary
> - Developer Rejected
> - Rejected
> - Metadata Rejected
> - Developer Removed from Sale
> - Removed from Sale

As described in a forum [post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121371?answerId=642951022#642951022) - the fastest way to be able to delete the tvOS app is to make the next version of the iOS app ("Prepare for Submission" state instead of "Ready for Sale"). You don't need to to actually upload a binary yet. But I suspect you have to input the desired correct version number, because I don't see a way to remove this iOS app later (in "Prepare for Submission" state).